# How do I send the mutable string to the NSTextField properly?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, label, nstextfield, nsmutablestring

So I have all this code that I have debugged and it seems to be fine. I made a mutable string and for some reason I can not get it to be displayed on my label. the debugger says

"2010-04-22 22:50:26.126 Fibonacci[24836:10b] *** -[NSTextField setString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x130150"

What is wrong with this? When I just send the string to NSLog, it comes out fine.

here's all my code, any help would be appreciated. "elementNum" is a comboBox and "display" is a Label.
Thanks

```
 #import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller

- (IBAction)computeNumber:(id)sender {
 int x = 1;
 int y = 1;
 NSMutableString *numbers = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 [numbers setString:@"1, 1,"];
 int num = [[elementNum objectValueOfSelectedItem]intValue];
 int count = 1;
 while (count<=num) {
  int z = y;
  y+=x;
  x=z;
  [numbers appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d,", y]];
  count++;
 }
 [display setString:numbers];
 NSLog(numbers);
}
@end


`
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but use appendFormat instead of appendString.

Comment: I think your question is a bit confusing, you say 'display' is a label but the error messages mentions NSTextField ?

Comment: drawnonward - thanks.
Anders Karlsson - It's an NSTextField, interface builder calls it a label so I did. I guess that is confusing though, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message you're getting:

```
-[NSTextField setString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x130150"
```

This is telling you something. Specifically, that `NSTextField` does not have a `-setString:` method and trying to call it will fail.

This is your cue to look at the docs for `NSTextField`. When you do so, you will see that there are no methods to set the string value. However, the docs also show you that `NSTextField` inherits from `NSControl`, which has a `-setStringValue:` method.

So, you need to call `-setStringValue:` to set the value of an `NSTextField`.

```
[display setStringValue:numbers];
```

Note that in your code at present, you are leaking the `numbers` string object. You created it using `-alloc`, so you are responsible for releasing it.

Instead, you should create it using `[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"1, 1,"]`, which will return an autoreleased object, as well as initializing it in the same message.

Comment: Thanks so much man. I'm new to computer programming and I've been trying to teach myself Cocoa. I looked up a couple things in the docs but I guess I should've looked up NSTextField. Thanks again.